# How to set different variable in a rails partial based on a condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to be able to pull different values from a database based on a condition that's evaluating the same table from the database, i.e. render one partial for several conditions? For example, in my index view, I have:

```
- @places.each do |place|
    - if place.level == 1
      = render 'place', one: palce 
    - elsif place.level == 2
      = render 'place', two: place
     - else
      = render 'place', none: place
```

Here is my partial:

```
%table.table
  %caption
    %h2= place.name
  %thead
  %tbody
    %tr
      %td
        Name:
      %td
        = place.place_name
    %tr
      %td
        Total rooms:
      %td
        = place.places_rooms
    %tr
      %td
        Total places:
      %td
        = place.places_count
```

What should my index page code partial look like?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It's unclear what effect the `place.level` should have based on the information you provided.

Comment: So, if the place.level value is 1 then the partial will pull different data from the database based on that level. Hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

What condition are you trying to render differently?

I ask because you are passing `place` as your local, but you designate one, two, and none as the locals, but they don't exist in your partial.  Without some more information, my only guess is that you  should be doing `= render 'place', place: place`

EDIT as requirement changed:

```
-@places.each do |place|
  = render 'place, place: place
```

partial

```
%table.table
  %caption
    %h2= place.name
  %thead
  %tbody
    %tr
      %td
        Name:
      %td
        = place.try(:"level_#{place.level}_place") || place.place_name
    %tr
      %td
        Total rooms:
      %td
        = place.places_rooms
    %tr
      %td
        Total places:
      %td
        = place.places_count
```

So I think that would be the way to do it.  But perhaps this should be a hint to you that your tables may be holding a lot of unnecessary fields.  Perhaps it would be better to create a levels table and then have create a relationship between them.

Comment: Good question Sean. So, I have a level in my place table, that's one, two, and so forth, based on this level I would like to render the partial. I don't know how to do that, though. What I am straggling with is how do I set variable one, two, and so forth in the partial? Hope I am making sense? Thanks.

Comment: It does make sense. But do you want to render this level inside the partial? otherwise I'd go with reseting the `@places` instance variable to `@places = Place.where(level: 1)` in your controller. obviously instead of 1 you could use params[:level] or something similar depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, Sean. Inside the partial is ideal.

Comment: Something like this, but this is not working, though. `=render partial: 'place', locals: {levels: [place.level, place.level > 0 ? 2 : nil]}`. What should my index look like and partial as well?

Comment: I tried to do What I think you are trying to achieve, but i'm still not entirely sure.  Where inside the partial are you trying to add the level data?  Or is level your condition for rendering the partial in the first place?

Comment: Sean, so, lets say you have different levels in your places table, 1, 2, 3, etc. Based on that level, you want to make partial pull different data from the same table, i.e with or without certain data.

Comment: I see. what other data are you trying to pull?

Comment: Hey,Sean, so basically, `if level one`, then `place.place_name` will not be showing, but `place.level_one_name`, something like that.

Comment: I would hate to make many partials for different levels,instead have on e partial.

Comment: Ok I see.  You could make it work with send. give me a moment and ill fix the partial.

Comment: So I think that would be the way to do it.  But perhaps this should be a hint to you that your tables may be holding a lot of unnecessary fields.  Perhaps it would be better to create a levels table and then have create a relationship between them.

Comment: You are right, Sean,but I am dealing with legacy data:( so can't remove those fields at all. One more thing, though, that number 1, is a string, 'one'. Thanks mate for help!

Comment: Oh, if its a string then you are fine. :)  let me revise my answer .

Comment: Thanks Sean. I'll try it shortly and let you know if it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Logic in the view layer is an anti-pattern since it makes the view less readable / less tied to the domain language.

Have you considered wrapping your `@places` in a [decorator object](http://bibwild.wordpress.com/2012/12/19/the-simplest-rails-decorator-implementation-that-just-might-work/) of your own creation? Assuming I understand the problem correctly (disclaimer: not 100% sure I do), here's what I might do:

Assuming that your controller is `PlacesController`...

```
# app/controllers/places_controller.rb

class PlacesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @places = PlaceWithLevels.decorate(places)
  end

  private

  def places
    Place.all
  end
end
```

Now we define the decorator object, `PlaceWithLevels` (you can probably come up w/ a better name for this, based on your domain):

```
# app/models/place_with_levels.rb

class PlaceWithLevels < SimpleDelegator
  def self.decorate(places)
    places.map do |place|
      self.new(place)
    end
  end

  # not sure what to name this since I'm not sure what you're
  # trying to accomplish, but note that this is the method we'll
  # be calling in the partial
  def foo
    case levels
    when 0; 'Text you want to show up when there are 0 levels'
    when 1; 'Text you want to show up when there is 1 level'
    when 2; 'Text you want to show up when there are 2 levels'
  end
end
```

Then, in the view:

```
# app/views/places/index.html.haml
= render @places
```

Notice that we don't need to call `@places.each` since `render` will call [#to_partial_path](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Conversion.html#method-i-to_partial_path) on each member of the collection in order to figure out which partial to render.
And finally, in the partial (method calls to `places_rooms`, etc will work here because of our use of `SimpleDelegator`, above):

```
# app/views/places/_place.html.haml
%table.table
  %caption
    %h2= place.name
  %thead
  %tbody
    %tr
      %td
        Name:
      %td
        = place.foo
    %tr
      %td
        Total rooms:
      %td
        = place.places_rooms
    %tr
      %td
        Total places:
      %td
        = place.places_count
```

Notice that we no longer need special logic here...just call the `name` method (or whatever the appropriate method should be) on our decorator object, but from the perspective of the view, the view doesn't need to know that it's working with anything other than a `place`.

This technique is also very useful if you need to render a completely different partial depending on the `level` attribute — simply define your own `to_partial_path` method on the decorator object, for example:

```
def to_partial_path
  case level
  when 0; 'zero_level_place'
  when 1; 'single_level_place'
  when 2; 'two_level_place'
end
```

Hope this helps!!!!

PS: I would also encourage you to also get rid of the `places_` prefixes on `places_rooms`, `places_count`, etc... better signal/noise ratio.

Comment: Thanks Anthony. This sounds like a very good idea. I haven't given a try yet, but I will do so on my next project.